Getting error as failed to persist file in jfrog artifactory oss
Getting error as no files cached and also Failed to persist file with sha1 while trying to download the artifacts from jfrog ui or even at server level also.
artifactory-service.log file says below

Failed to download 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/2020.0.6/spring-session-bom-2020.0.6.pom'. Received status code 200 and caught exception: Failed to persist file with sha1: ea3f628faytuygvhb765755e1ea65f91fdae52a0
2024-04-25T07:14:24.278Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [3cbed23bd0e8e025] [o.a.r.v.i.PomInterceptor:133  ] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-10] - Failed to persist file with sha1: ea3f628faytuygvhb765755e1ea65f91fdae52a0
2024-04-25T07:14:24.694Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [6f80857ee213b378] [o.a.r.HttpRepo:464            ] [http-nio-8081-exec-6] - repo1 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/2020.0.6/spring-session-bom-2020.0.6.pom 2.66 KB


I found the issue, as there was a duplicate directory of ea at
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/filestore/ea
Hence i deleted the whole ea directory itself, and it resolved my issue.

Possible Causes:

Disk Space Issues: JFrog Artifactory might be running out of disk space to store the downloaded file.
Permission Issues: The user running JFrog Artifactory might not have permission to write to the storage location.
File Corruption: There could be a temporary issue causing file corruption during the persistence process.

Troubleshooting Steps:

Check Disk Space: Verify that JFrog Artifactory has sufficient disk space available. You can find instructions on checking disk space in the JFrog Artifactory documentation.
Review Permissions: Ensure the user running JFrog Artifactory has write permissions to the storage location where artifacts are saved.
Restart JFrog Artifactory: Sometimes a simple restart can resolve temporary glitches that might be causing the persistence issue.
Check Logs for Additional Details: The artifactory-service.log file might contain more specific information about the cause of the error. Look for entries around the timestamp mentioned in the error message (07:14:24).

Additional Resources:

The Stack Overflow question you linked provides a similar scenario and potential solutions: Artifactory: Failed to persist file; Status code: 404 / Gradle
JFrog Artifactory documentation can be found on their website: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation

By following these steps and referring to the resources, you should be able to identify the root cause of the "Failed to persist file with sha1" error and resolve the issue with downloading artifacts in JFrog Artifactory.
